# Trying to add a string object to an integer

Tags: c++, string, integer, addition

This is probably a very basic question for which I have been searching on google for the last 20 mins. I am not sure if i am phrasing it correctly, but I am not getting an explanation that I understand.

Basically, I have a string object and when I add an integer value x, it shortens the string by x characters.

Here is the code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

void Print::print(std::string str)
{
   std::cout << str << std::endl;    
}


print("formatString:" + 5);
```

The output is: tString:

Now i realise that the above is incorrect and during my search I have found ways correct the behaviour, but I haven’t found what is actually happening internally for me to get the above result.

Thanks

Comment: String literals are `const char[N]`, not `std::string`.

Answer (score 2):

The answer is simple: Pointer arithmetic.

Your string literal (array of `const char` including implicit 0-terminator), decays to a `const char*` on use, which you increment and pass to your `print()`-function, thus invoking the `std::string`-constructor for string literals.

So, yes, you start with a string object (0-terminated array of `const char`), but not a `std::string` object.

Answer (score 1):

> Basically, I have a string object

No, you do not have a string object. `"formatString:"` is not a `std::string`, but a "string" literal. It is in fact a `const char*`. A `const char*` has a `operator +` defined that takes an integer and advances the value of the pointer with a number of positions. In your case it's 5.

To get a compiler error you'd have to wrap the literal in a `std::string`.

```
print(std::string("formatString:") + 5);
```

Comment: "To get a compiler error you'd have to wrap the literal in a std::string." - LOL

Comment: A string literal is actually a `const char[]` (C++11, §2.14.5/8).  The array is just decaying to a pointer here.</pedantry>

Answer (score 0):

"formatString:" is a string literal that has type `const char[14]`  That is it is an array of const char with size equal to 14 (the array includes the terminating zero).
In expressions like this

```
"formatString:" + 5
```

the array is implicitly converted to a pointer to its first element. So if for example `const char *p` denotes this pointer then the expression looks as

```
p + 5
```

The result of the expression is a pointer that points to the element of the array with index 5. That is there is used the pointer arithmetic.

`P + 5` points to the first symbol of string "tString" 
And this expression is used by the constructor of class std::string.

Answer (score 0):

Examine the following,

```
#include <iostream>

void print(std::string str)
{
    std::cout << str << std::endl;
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    //following two lines created implicitly by the compiler
    const char* pstr = "formatString";
    std::string tmp(pstr + 5);  //string c-tor: string (const char* s);
    
    // now tmp: --> "tString"
    
    print(tmp);
    
    return 0;
}
```

`pstr` is a pointer and you are doing [pointer arithmetic](http://www.learncpp.com/cpp-tutorial/68-pointers-arrays-and-pointer-arithmetic/) when you use `+` operation.

**Note**:Compiler may create different internal structure, but it is a instructive way to think the above two lines.